# Postgres password.so (passwordcheck) library does not exist

Tags: postgresql, passwords

Apologies in advance because this may be a really stupid question. I'm pretty new to Postgres so very well may have managed to do something incorrectly during installation. But I'm trying to enable the passwordcheck module/functionality in my Postgres 11 environment on a RHEL 8 server.  I've seen many references saying this is accomplished by simply:

add '$libdir/passwordcheck' to shared_preload_libraries in postgresql. conf, then restart the server

However, when i do this, I get the following upon restarting Postgres:

FATAL:  could not access file "$libdir/passwordcheck": No such file or directory

I've searched my Postgres libraries and just as the error indicates, cannot find a file named passwordcheck.so anywhere.  From reading the Postgres documentation, i thought passwordcheck(.so) was supposed to be part of the standard install and therefore available by default.

Can someone/anyone tell me what I'm missing or doing incorrectly?  Is it possible to download this module/library somehow?  I'd hate to have to completely reinstall Postgres from scratch since everything else in my environment seems to be working perfectly.

This is my first time submitting to Stackoverflow, so apologies if I've missed or breached any etiquette.   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This extension is part of "contrib".  RH policy is not to install contrib unless requested.  Do something like `sudo yum install postgresql-contrib`

Comment: I know the instructions in this comment box say not to say "Thank you", but it seems rude not to do so.  THANK YOU very much.  The fact that passwordcheck was not part of the standard/default Postgres install was not obvious to me.  Just for technical correctness and for others' sake, i do want to mention that under RHEL 8 I had to use dnf instead of yum.  But postgresql-contrib was the issue.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

passwordcheck is an extension part of the source distribution: it's an extension coded in C and that cannot be installed only with 'CREATE EXTENSION;'. They are usually built using PostgreSQL source code.

Actually there is the possibility to download extension binaries with a RPM:
see https://centos.pkgs.org/7/postgresql-11-x86_64.